# Attempt to read property "id" on null in Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i got a problem my code is:

```
if($user->plan->id == 1) {
    return view($this->activeTemplate . 'user.autopool', compact('pageTitle', 'commissions', 'deposit', 'transactions', 'commission', 'withdraw', 'transaction', 'username', 'balance', 'user', 'plans'));
} else {
    return view($this->activeTemplate . 'user.nopool', compact('pageTitle', 'user'));
}
```

[image]

i want to get rid of this error from my code. i am stucking here.

Comment: The `plan` property is null on the `$user` object. Without more context, we cannot help you anymore than that. Check how the `plan` relation is instanciated and make sure it's loaded.

Comment: plan property is not found on the $user object.  you should share the user & plan model code as well.

Answer (score 1):

`$user->plan` evaluates to null. You don't guard against this.

---

- If you're using PHP8, you can use the nullsafe operator.

```php
if ($user->plan?->id)
```

- If you're using PHP7, you can use laravel's `optional()` function.

```php
if (optional($user->plan)->id)
```

- If the relationship between `User` and `Plan` is a belongsTo relationship (User belongsTo Plan), you might be better off just using the foreign key in the user model.

```php
if ($user->plan_id)
```